# having trouble understanding how to load json and iterate through it

Tags: python, json

I have the following JSON document:

```
[
    {
        "iLevel": 85,
        "isEthereal": true,
        "quality": "Normal",
        "stats": [
            {
                "name": "item_splashonhit",
                "value": 100
            }
        ],
        "type": "Legendary Mallet"
    },
    {
        "defense": 720,
        "iLevel": 88,
        "isEthereal": true,
        "quality": "Normal",
        "sockets": 4,
        "type": "Diamond Mail"
    },
    {
        "defense": 732,
        "iLevel": 69,
        "isEthereal": true,
        "quality": "Normal",
        "type": "Boneweave"
    }
]
```

Here is the code I've put together so far and the error. I think that it is perhaps the JSON format which is wrong?

```
# packages
import json
from json import JSONEncoder
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Collection

# get all json files in 'json' folder
folderPath = '.\\json\\'
jsonFiles = (f for f in Path(folderPath).glob("*") if f.is_file())

for j in jsonFiles:
    fileCont = open(j.resolve())
    for f in fileCont:
        obj = json.loads(f)
        print(obj.name, obj.quality, obj.ilevel, obj.type)
    fileCont.close()
```

I also don't think I am using the 'json' library correctly. Sorry I am still very new to python.
Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\script.py", line 17, in <module>
    obj = json.loads(d)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 3)
```

Any help is appreciated. Once I get through this I'll be looking to iterate through the 'stats' object as well but I'll cross that bridge later. I just want 'print()' to output the values so I know I am working with objects correctly.

Comment: My guess: There is no `name`, `quality`, `ilevel`, or `type` property in the object you provided. So even if you decoded it, it won't work.

Comment: And also, the object is an array (`[]`), not an actual object (`{}`).

Comment: Well yes, it is a list of json objects within each contains name, quality, ilvl, and type keys. So how can I load the file, decode the json, iterate through the objects in the list, and output the values of each key?

Answer (score 0):

The is one subtle trick, which you should pay attention for and thats the load functionality of json :

```
json.loads() - should be used for a string-like files
json.load()  - should be used for a file-like objects
```

So if i was you, I would start like this :

```
for j in jsonFiles:
    with open(j, "r") as f:
        t = json.load(f)
        for i in t:
            i.get("stats") # returns None if nothing found
```